# Removing the need for "?" or page name for IIS6 in order to process link shortener URLs

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting, iis-6

Working on a URL shortener in asp.net running on IIS6. Trying to avoid installing URL rewriting software so looking for pure ASP solution.

Is there a way to process links in this format:

```
shorten.me/AugustSale
```

We are already able to process

```
shorten.me/page.aspx?AugustSale
shorten.me/?AugustSale
```

but these are not very human-friendly.

Any ideas?

If the solution requires installing a URL-rewriter, could you recommend one which could be installed for one site only and not for the rest of the sites on the server?

Edit: We are running a complex, resource-heavy CMS on another virtual site and have been warned against installing a URL-rewriter.

Comment: Is shorten.me a virtual folder?

Comment: Yes, it is a virtual site under IIS6. And, this is not the real URL.

Comment: Then why not make "AugustSale" a virtual and set the default page to "page.aspx".

Comment: Because we are building a link shortening app allowing people to create their own short links with optional parameters and track statistics. The app is ready, the only issue is with the URL format.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) for our IIS6 boxes and haven't had any issues with it.  It also has a mapping feature that might prove useful to your situation.

Oh... and it's FREE.  WooHoo! (well, donation based anyway, so help support them if you can).

Rewrite based upon a map file:
http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/77dd5ab8-9638-45e9-a920-6182fca3f767.htm

Edit - configurable at the vdir level

> IIRF.ini: the ini files specific for each virtual directory or IIS
>   application. There should be one of these files for each specific
>   vdir, or IIS Application. The settings specified here include settings
>   for the URLs that should be rewritten, redirected, or proxied; whether
>   the IIRF engine should be enabled for that vdir or application; and so
>   on. For each installation of IIRF, you will provide at least one, and
>   possibly many more, IIRF.ini files.

Comment: Is it possible to enable it only for specific virtual sites and not enable it for the rest of the server?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  It's installed at the IIS level, but you have to configure it to run at the virtual level.

Comment: So if it is not added on the virtual level, it will not run? We are running a complex, resource-heavy CMS on another virtual site and have been warned against installing a URL-rewriter.

Comment: @aaandre - It "runs" at the IIS level as it's an ISAPI filter, but it won't process any requests for virtual sites that are not configured or turned off via the INI file.